# Cannot find the files filling up my /var partition

Tags: ubuntu, disk-usage, var

I'm running a python application that keeps crashing with
`sqlite3.OperationalError: database or disk is full`, even though I have 300G in the partition where this is installed and from where I'm running it.

However, I noticed my `/var` partition is being filled and emptied while the application is running, and that it is 90% full. I saw this with System Monitor.

Turns out that when I see the partitions with Baobab, I see only 6G available of 50G in that partition. However...

```
$ sudo du -sh /var/
8.4G    /var/
```

I simply cannot see the files/directories saturating my `/var` directory,

Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: You can use `df -i` to see the number of used inodes, which might be hurting you. This may or may not help

Comment: Maybe you have deleted files that are still open, check `lsof`.

Comment: Please add output of `df -h /var` to your question

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to install `ncdu` which is basically a combination of `tree` and `ls` and use it like below:

`ncdu /` or `ncdu /var/` and then navigate with arrow keys to find out files or directories saturating your device.

This is not a well-known method but always works for me.